# How to downgrade SonarQube 6.0 to SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS

Tags: sonarqube, upgrade

I am using SonarQube 6.0 on our one of the server1 and wanted to run SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS version on server2 stopping service on Server 2. I was able to run SonarQube 6.0 on Server 2 but when I'm upgrading it to SonarQube 5.6.5 LTS it gives me error - Database was upgraded to a more recent of SonarQube. Backup must probably be restored or db settings are incorrect.

I tried upgrading couple of time and everytime I get same error and again I had to restore my database for SonarQube 6.0. Could anyone know how to resolve this issue. Actually I have followed steps mentioned in the documements as well but didn't not succeed.

Answer (score 5):

Going from 6.0 to 5.6.5 LTS is *not* an upgrade. It's a *downgrade*. Your attempts are failing because there is no support for downgrading a database.

If you really want to move to 5.6.5, you'll have to start over with an empty schema.

Comment: I'm talking about 5.6.* LTS version. We have two different versions LTS and non-LTS. LTS is more stable version than non-LTS version i.e. SonarQube 6.*.  I have project analysis done for various projects using SonarQube 6.* and wanted to switch over to LTS version as its more stable one. Could you please tell me my assumption are wrong or right. Should I stick to 6.* version?

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference between SonarQube 6.* and SonarQube 5.x LTS versions?

Comment: @RasikBapotra check the release notes [linked from here](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) or the [announcements](https://blog.sonarsource.com/tag/screenshots/)